# Javascript dynamic showing of images not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am following a JS tutorial and ran into some problems

Currently learning dynamic way of displaying images using javascript.

No matter how many times I listen and re-code, add/remove unnecessary semicolons, slashes or anything.. it just doesn't work.

I've tried this 3 days ago when it worked, copied the same thing and still no improvements, it just shows a blank html document with no images displaying.

If I write the static version, the images display properly, but that's a lot of images and DIVs in the html file.

I'm starting to wonder if there is a problem with the folders placement & orders, and importing of the files.

-Desktop > website > frontend > src > index.html, style.css, app.js, data.js,

-Desktop > website > frontend > src > screens > template-generator.js

-Desktop > website > frontend > src > images > (all images)

I am using Bootstrap 5 Framework.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!------------------------------------------------------Fonts & BS Plugins-------------------------------------------------------------->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="portfolio-section" id="portfolio">
      <div class="container padding text-center"><br><br><br><br><br>
        <h2>PORTFOLIO</h2>
        <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
        <div class="row padding text-center">
          <div class="col-lg-3"><a href="" class="portfolio-menu"><h3>L0GOS</h3></a></div>
          <div class="col-lg-3"><a href="" class="portfolio-menu"><h3>P0STERS</h3></a></div>
          <div class="col-lg-3"><a href="" class="portfolio-menu"><h3>TYP0GRAPHY</h3></a></div>
          <div class="col-lg-3"><a href="" class="portfolio-menu"><h3>RENDERS</h3></a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!----------------------- IMAGES CONTENT USING CSS & JS ------------------------->
    <main id="main-container">
      <!--Image displaying using JS-->
    </main>
  </body>
```

This is the "data.js" file (List of all images):

```
export default {
  logos: [
    {
      _id: '1',
      name: 'GM HAUS Logo',
      image: '/images/logo-1.jpg',
    },
    {
      _id: '2',
      name: 'Doom Bikes Logo',
      image: '/images/logo-2.jpg',
    },
    {
      _id: '3',
      name: 'CCNA 200-301 Logo',
      image: '/images/logo-3.jpg',
    },
    {
      _id: '4',
      name: 'Trailscapes Logo',
      image: '/images/logo-4.jpg',
    },
    {
      _id: '5',
      name: 'Pro Code Logo',
      image: '/images/logo-5.jpg',
    },
    {
      _id: '6',
      name: 'Grove Hill Wine Logo',
      image: '/images/logo-6.jpg',
    },
  ],
};
```

This is the "template-generator.js"

```
import data from '../data.js';

const Gallery = {
  render: () => {
    const { logos } = data;
    return `
      <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center logos">
          ${logos.map( 
            (logo) => `
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="logo">
              <a href="/#/logo/${logo._id}">
                <img src="${logo.image}" alt="${logo.name}" class="img-fluid">
              </a>
              <div class="logo-name">
                <a href="/#/logo/1">
                  ${logo.name}
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          `)}
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
  },
};
export default Gallery;
```

This is the "app.js" (where the app gets loaded):

```
import Gallery from './screens/template-generator.js';

const router = () => {
  const main = document.getElementById("main-container");
  main.innerHTML = Gallery.render();
}
window.addEventListener("load", router);
```

Comment: do you see any error in the console logs in chrome's inspect elements menu? That would help us in debugging the issue more accurately

Comment: Where are you including your `app.js` in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Just from a quick look I noticed the "$" syntax here:

```
<img src="${logo.image}" alt="${logo.name}" class="img-fluid">
```

If you intended to use Template Strings, then the syntax is incorrect. Template Strings should be wrapped inside backtick, not double or single quotes. So instead, your code should look like this:

```
<img src=`${ logo.image }` alt=`${ logo.name }` class="img-fluid">
```

Comment: The whole body of the function is in backticks: starts in `(logo) => \``. So, the entire thing is a template literal, the `${}` will be correctly interpolated.